# Copy different folder from text

Tags: file, batch-file, text, copy, maps

Can someone please help me?

I have a .txt file with different folders and i need to copy all the folder to another folder.

this is how the .txt looks like.

```
F:\Coinops\XBOX\G\Emulators\Vision 4\- VISION Media\- Shoot em ups\sky soldier
F:\Coinops\XBOX\G\Emulators\Vision 4\- VISION Media\- Run n Gun\tnk 3
F:\Coinops\XBOX\G\Emulators\Vision 4\- VISION Media\- Action Games\tutankham
F:\Coinops\XBOX\G\Emulators\Vision 4\- VISION Media\- Action Games\donkey kong 2
```

there are 595 maps that i need to copy.

(sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "targetFolder=x:\some\where"

    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("filelist.txt") do (
        xcopy "%%~fa\*" "%targetFolder%\%%~nxa" /y /i /e 
    )
```

The `for` command reads the lines in the input file. Each line is stored in the `%%a` replaceable parameter and for it a `xcopy` command is executed to copy from the full path of the readed source folder (`%%~fa`) to the target folder with the name and extension of the source folder added (`%%~nxa`)